# Can I replace optical drive with 2nd hard disk on MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware-recommendation

I have a unibody MacBook, late 2008 I think. The optical drive failed and I wondered about adding a second hard disk. Is this simple to do?

Comment: [Here's a video about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96JHPof5JnU). I don't think you can do it without buying a case for the drive. The one they use in the video only works for a SATA optical drives, check to see if your computer is compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard good things about the [Optibay kit](http://www.mcetech.com/optibay/). It provides a mounting bracket for whatever hard drive or SSD you want to put in there.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIwMs7ZgFws) shows how to install it in a Mid-2010 MBP, which is close in design to the Unibody MacBook you have. Instructions according to the guy in the video:

1. Remove the bottom panel
2. Disconnect and remove the Wi-Fi/Bluetooth antenna.
3. Disconnect optical drive and put the connector onto the Optibay
4. Put your hard drive into the optibay
5. Follow the steps in reverse to reassemble your computer.

The dangerous parts are when you pop up the delicate connectors with, say, an iPod opening tool. So the Wi-Fi may not work afterwards, and you would be on your own since Apple doesn't support modifications. But overall, it isn't so bad. It looks like an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've done it with OWC's Data Doubler and it worked extremely well.  Check out http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/drive_bracket/datadoubler/